# How to remove empty column in excel report generated by JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-excel

I am using iReport to design JasperReports. Excel exported report is contains extra empty columns, I tried doing

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
```

and

```
excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
```

But the empty column is still getting displayed. Is there a way to remove this empty column from the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact report layout. That option is great when you have fields that are not adjoining. But with more complex layouts sometimes there are columns which are mostly blank.

The quickest solution is probably to layout the report better to avoid any space between fields.

Comment: I have found that from some article, it is because of not using grid while designing

Comment: Yes, the option you used is valid and useful... but it's not sufficient in all cases. Manually modifying your layout should always be able to solve it (but it's likely to require a bit more work).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POI, it doesn´t work. I walked around it using JExcelApiExporter instead JRXlsExporter.

JExcelApiExporter is packed in a jxl jar. In my case jxl-2.6.10 for jasperreports 4.0.2

```
        // Ejecucion de jasper report por ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = rsvp.sql.MyConnection.getConnection().execQuery(m_query);
        JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

        // Parametros del reporte
        m_param.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(m_reportFileName, m_param, resultSetDataSource);

        // Crea Excel Exporter
        //JRExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();  // Este es de POI, no funciona bien
        JRExporter exporter = new JExcelApiExporter();

        // Configura el exporter
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFileName);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.TRUE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);

        // Exporta a Excel
        exporter.exportReport();
```